# aws IAM role is not authorized to perform: route53:ListHostedZones

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-route53, aws-policies

When I try to deploy terraform script using gitlab runner I am getting the following error

`Error: Error finding Route 53 Hosted Zone: AccessDenied: User: arn:aws:sts::12345678:assumed-role/dev-runner/i-01b2f123f1e1a127c is not authorized to perform: route53:ListHostedZones because no identity-based policy allows the route53:ListHostedZones action`

The IAM role that is attached to the runner has the following policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": [                
                "arn:aws:route53:::*",
                "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:12345678:certificate/*",                
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

What I am missing here? All the actions are allowed on `arn:aws:route53:::*` resource.

Comment: The `JSON` is not valid. You should remove `,` after `"arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:12345678:certificate/*"`. Is it typo?

Comment: yes its typo here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check role with [AWS Policy Simulator](https://policysim.aws.amazon.com/home/index.jsp)

Here is

> This action does not support resource-level permissions. Policies granting access must specify "*" in the resource element.

error is raising with your role.

Resource should be `"Resource": *` to be able run `ListHostedZones`. However, in this case the permissions will be totally insecure, so I recommend to separate the statements:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "route53:ListHostedZones",
                ... any other specific permissions for R53 ...
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": [                
                "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:12345678:certificate/*"              
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

<sub><sup>And just a personal opinion: using wildcard `*` actions without specifying at least services (`route53:*`) is not looking like a good idea</sup></sub>